# Angular-Messages sometimes aren't shown when used with Angular-Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular-Messages with Angular-Material v1.0.9. I have an `md-dialog` inside which I have a form with fields created with `ng-repeat`:

```
<form name="modal.dynamicForm" flex="80" layout="column">
    <md-input-container ng-repeat="field in modal.model.fields">
        <ng-form name="innerForm">
            <label>{{ field.label }}*</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="field.value" name="{{ field.name }}" ng-pattern="field.pattern" required />
            <div ng-messages="innerForm[field.name].$error">
                <div ng-message="required">{{ 'fieldRequired' | translate }}</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">{{ field.patternError }}</div>
            </div>
        </ng-form>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

Angular-Messages are used to display form errors. The problem is that when I use both `required` and `pattern` messages, they are sometimes shown and sometimes not. It worked properly when there was no regexp check. The scenario is for example:

1. I have a field which needs to be a number. I enter wrong value, e.g. a text - error message is displayed.
2. I delete value from field so that it's empty. Now `required` error should be displayed, but it is not. There is a red border informing about the error, though.
3. Now I enter a correct value, e.g. 10 - there is no message as expected.
4. Again, I enter wrong value - now error is displayed.

The above scenario can be repeated and is always true - I need to enter a correct value before error is displayed again.

I've found one workaround which is to add `md-auto-hide` to container with `ng-messages`, but now errors are displayed even just after opening the modal window which is not what I want. Have anyone faced a similar issue and found any solution? I'll be grateful for any help.

---

**Edit**

I've created a fiddle which presents the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/t3xjrL19/2/

Comment: Just give it a try... could you set multiple in your div ng-messages , such as follows: `<div ng-messages="innerForm[field.name].$error" multiple>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that. I tried to use this as well and the effect was unfortunately the same.

Comment: mmm...so no idea, sorry, maybe you could put your code in a plunker. In the app I'm working I've the same use case (one required and one pattern validation) and is just working fine.

Comment: I will try to prepare the plunker later :)

Comment: Added a jsfiddle - if you follow steps from the scenario you should be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: you use a specific pattern? in your fiddle you can use types to avoid texto and use only number, also set a max or just is an example ?

Comment: For now it's only a number but there might be situation where validation will be more complex. That's why I'd rather like to use the `ng-pattern` and `ng-messages`. Forms will be sent from the server so I should be prepared for different scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem should disappear if you conditionally show your `<div ng-messages .../>` using both `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

Example using `ng-if` (displaying the div if the field form is touched and there is a validation error)

```
<div ng-messages="innerForm[field.name].$error" ng-if="innerForm[field.name].$touched && innerForm[field.name].$error" multiple>
...
</div>
```

To be honest, I would have thought it would worked as you used it before I saw this question, but maybe you can use my suggestion as a workaround.

I've forked your fiddle to try it and it seems to be working pretty well. Could you check it?

> See working forked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fd9vqsL/2/)

Hope it helps

*PS: For your use case, attribute `multiple` is unnecessary because you will always show one validation message at the same time.*